# stylus string interpolation styntax for :before pseudo selector using a for loop

Tags: stylus

I'm trying to make

```
#others li .text1:before{
    content: "text1";
}...
```

by doing

```
#others li
    for label in text1 text2 text3
        .{label}:before
            content {label}
```

But syntax isn't right it seems... it gives error

> expected "indent", got "outdent"

The error is for `content {label}` bit, because without it the class selectors (`.text1:before`) prints ok

And with `content '{label}'` it prints out `{label}` as is.

Answer (score 3):

Stylus don't have interpolation in strings or idents for values, you could use addition to string, this would convert the ident to string:

```
#others li
    for label in text1 text2 text3
        .{label}:before
            content ''+label
```